# Schedule subroutines in perl

Tags: perl

I'm parsing a log file, and I'm required to produce JSON file with results for every 1 second, 5, 5 min, 15, 30, 1 hour ..etc

I'm confused about the concept here, it is possible to write one big infinite while loop that include number of subroutines each will perform its parsing based on different time interval.

Here is I have so far, not sure if this is the right approach

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$ | = 1; # Ensure output appears

my $interval = 1;
my @command = "echo processing ...";

my $count = 0;

while (1) {
    `since access.log | json_convert.pl 

    sleep $interval - time % $interval;
    system @command;
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be Perl code? It's full of syntax errors. It's also not clear from your question what the problem is. You should [edit] your question and include example input and output data.

Comment: I'm confused with your question. I even wonder if you understand what you are tasked to do.

Comment: I wanted to run different tasks at different time intervals in one script without depending on linux task scheduler such as "at, cron ..etc" , so I have created number of subroutines for each of required tasks, however I was confused on how I can go about executing these tasks in timely manner,  @Borodin  solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeated `sleep` calls will drift rapidly because they don't take into account the time spent creating the JSON data. I would also be very wary of using `system` calls to do the data manipulation as it is bound to slow things down, and you may well overrun the one-second response time that you are looking for. Do it all within Perl instead

I recommend you look at the excellent [`EV`](https://p3rl.org/EV) module. The *periodic* event type is what you need

Here's a very short example. Your own callback subroutine should examine the time at which it is called to determine what to do, according to whether it is a multiple of 5 seconds, 60 seconds etc. Alternatively you could set up multiple event loops, one for each interval. The module makes it very straighforward

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use EV;
use Time::Piece 'localtime';

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $one_second = EV::periodic 1, 1, 0, \&callback;

sub callback {
  say "Periodic event at ", localtime(EV::now)->hms;
};

EV::run;
```

#### output

```
Periodic event at 10:27:36
Periodic event at 10:27:37
Periodic event at 10:27:38
Periodic event at 10:27:39
Periodic event at 10:27:40
```

etc.